# Bind location in bing maps xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, bing-maps

How to Bind location in bing maps( Longitude & Latitude ) ??

after created a maps i would like bind more than one location and i trying in this code but not work why ?

```
            <bm:Map Height="350" Credentials="xxxxxxxxxxxx" x:Name="Map" ZoomLevel="16" Margin="-27,28,10,78">

            <bm:Map.Center>
                <bm:Location Latitude="{Binding Longitude}" Longitude="{Binding Latitude}"/>
            </bm:Map.Center>

        </bm:Map>
```

Comment: "i would like bind more than one location", what does that mean? Do you want to show objects (e.g. pushpins) on top of the map?

Comment: on my application 20 places and I want to show a map of each place so i need bind all locations of the places

Comment: Take a look at the [MapItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.mapitemscontrol.aspx). Find a code example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620947.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind a collection of items as such.

```
<Maps:Map x:Name="Map" CredentialsProvider="BlaaBlaaBlaa" ZoomLevel="16" Margin="-27,28,10,78">
    <Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
        <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Maps:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}" Content="{Binding Name}"
                                Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">

                </Maps:Pushpin>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </Maps:MapItemsControl>
</Maps:Map>
```

In this example I have a property `Locations` that is a collection of `MapLocation` objects

```
// DataContext
public ObservableCollection<MapLocation> Locations { get; private set; }
```

And the MapLocation class

```
public class MapLocation
{
    public GeoCoordinate Location { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: whats the reference ? maps not define !

Comment: I used "Maps" where you used "bm". Replace "Maps" with "bm" in your xaml